# Правильность кода

Tags: c#

Как правильней писать

```
List<Row> Txt;
public Text()
{
    Txt = new List<Row>();
}
```

Или так

```
List<Row> Txt = new List<Row>();
public Text()
{
 // методы
}
```

И почему?

Comment: Нет разницы. Оно вроде даже в один и тот же байт код в итоге скомпилируется.

Comment: @Suvitruf, вроде разница _может быть_, где-то был подобный вопрос...